# How to fix error of appending a literal string to a C string?

Tags: c++, string, function, pointers, c-strings

My last function is not working. This function appends a literal string to a C string. It checks if there is enough space in the C string to append the literal string to it. If there is not enough space, the C string length must be expanded to twice the size of the (literal string length + C string length). Then it can append the literal string to the C string. After I run the program and enter a text string, the first output statement is displayed and then after I keep getting an error of "terminate called after throwing an instance of std::bad_alloc" and the program stops working. All the other functions work before this append function. Is there a way to fix the last append function to work?

```
int main()
{
char* s1 = assign();            
char* s2 = assign(" C++ "); 



char* s3 = add(s1, s2);
cout << "length of \"" << s3 << "\" is " << strlen(s3) << endl;


 append(s3, "programming language");   // This function doesn't work
 cout << "length of \"" << s3 << "\" is " << strlen(s3) << endl;

return 0;
}


char* assign()
{
const int SIZE = 100;
char temp[SIZE];
int length;
int twicelen;

cout << "Enter a text string which will be used to append literal strings to it: ";
cin.getline(temp, SIZE);
length = strlen(temp);
twicelen = length * 2;


char* newCstring = new char[twicelen];
strcpy(newCstring, temp);

return newCstring;
}



char* assign(string str)
{
int len = strlen(str.c_str());
int newlen = len * 2;
char* newStr = new char[newlen];

strcpy(newStr, str.c_str());;

return newStr;
}


char* add(char* s1, char* s2)
{
strcat(s1, s2);
return s1;
}


void append(char* s3, string literalStr)  // Every function before this works and this is where the program gives an error and closes.
{


if (sizeof(s3) < (strlen(s3) + strlen(literalStr.c_str()) + 1))
{
    int expandLength = (strlen(s3) + strlen(literalStr.c_str())) * 2;
    char* s3 = new char[expandLength];
    strcat(s3, literalStr.c_str());

}
else
    strcat(s3, literalStr.c_str());

}
```

Comment: Why don't you use std::string?

Comment: Are you learning about pointers? Because otherwise you should be using `std::string`.

Comment: Add some output to show the value of `sizeof(s3)`. It's not what you think it is.

Comment: sizeof(s3) probably returns 1 because it gets size of the pointer. I'm not sure what you are going to achieve on that line

Comment: @Pooya - it will almost certainly not be 1. That would be a rather unusual architecture. Maybe some DSP, but not a mainstream computer.

Comment: @Pete you are right my mistake any way your point is correct it is not a useful data

Comment: @Joachim This is for my assignment and I'm not allowed to use `std::string`. The requirements are to only use C strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1:**

Your implementation of `add()` might cause a buffer overflow:

Here's what you have in main:

```
char* s1 = assign();  // here memory is allocated for the string you input          
char* s2 = assign(" C++ ");  // here memory is allocated again 

char* s3 = add(s1, s2);  // <====  ouch
```

Unfortunately,  `add()` just makes a strcat() without ensuring that the target string has enough memory.  From then onwards, you are in the frightening world of UB.  Anything could hapen.  For example, the ending null of the string might get lost, causing `strlen()` to find a huge length and cause a bad memory exception when you try to allocate twice such a huge number.

**Issue 2:**

Your `append()` function itself is flawed.

First, `sizeof(s3)` is the size of the pointer s3, so a pretty small number.  It's NOT the size of allocated bytes.  So there are big chances that you'll enter in the `if` block (but for the wrong reasons).

Next, you allocate a new `s3`. The problem is that the value you store in `s3` in the funtion is local to the function.  Nothing will happen to the pointer `s3` in main, still pointing to the original place.

To correct this second issue, you need to pass the pointer by reference.  Or change the function's signature to return the `s3` pointer. In this case you'd write in main:  `s3 = append (s3, ...);`

Comment: I'm required to make the `append()` a void function and not return anything. To correct the second issue, if I want to pass the pointer by reference how would I do that? I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Mark ok! just put an & before s3 in the argument declaration.

Comment: would it look like this `void append(char &s3, string literalStr)`? I tried declaring it this way `void append(char *&s3, string literalStr)` which didn't work.

Comment: It should look like the second form.  It didn't work, because in your if-bloc you redefine s3 as a local variable to the if bloc (that hides the parameter.  Don't write `char *s3 = new ...`  but just `s3 = new ...`.  [Demo](http://ideone.com/yXcomL)

Comment: A yes !  And after you have reallocated the memory for s3, you should copy the string that was at the old place, and free the memory that is no longer used.

Comment: I understand now! Thank you very much for your help!